# Como extraer datos de un input y guardarlos en un archivo txt o html con Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo un formulario basico, quisiera que los valores de los 2 input que tengo se guarden en un archivo html o txt al ejecutar el submit.

Como es el codigo para hacer eso, como los datos del input los guardo en un archivo html y que cada vez que le de click al boton me edite ese archivo html no me cree otro, que siempre sea el mismo archivo html como que si el html fuese una base de datos, siempre se sobre escriba.

Si me pueden ayudar con alguna idea, o me pueden decir que investigo se los agradeceria muchisimo..

Hasta ahora tengo esto, el script extrae el valor de los input y cuando le doy click al submit aparecen los datos en alerta, como hago para que en vez de alerta se vayan añadiendo a un archivo html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
                                                {
        $("#signInSubmit").click(function () {

         alert($("#ap_email").val());
         alert($("#ap-credential-autofill-hint").val());

         });
         });
```

Comment: Cuando te refieres a añadir a un archivo html, es visualizarlo en la misma pagina?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que buscas es añadir elementos cuando el usuario de click al botón de enviar y que dichos elementos se visualicen en tu `html`, lo puedes realizar de la siguiente manera, utilizando `jquery` (como lo vienes haciendo) y el metodo `.append`.

```js
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    /*evita la recarga de la pagina*/ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var valores = $("#ingresar").val();
    var caja = $(".contenido");

    caja.append("<p>"+ valores +"</p>");

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Stackoverflow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <label for="ingresar">Ingresar</label>
        <input type="text" name="ingresar" id="ingresar">
        <button id="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>

    <div class="contenido"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Ahora, si intentas enviar todos los datos recibidos a un `.txt` a través de `Javascript`, te recomiendo que visualices el siguiente [articulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055391/writing-data-to-a-local-text-file-with-javascript)